# Can you just "cp" copy and make a backup of a virtual disc image?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu, disk-image

Basically the tittle.

I'm doing Linux From Scratch(LFS), I'm at the point of installing the system software. Before doing that, I want to have a backup of the virtual drive that I'm installing LFS into, so I can use the half prepared drive as a template to make multiple LFS systems. I have a qemu-img disc image "lfs.img". Since I don't know how exactly virtual discs work, I don't know if I can create a backup by just making another copy of the image like you copy a normal file.

So does simply copying virtual disc images make a backup copy of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes
You can simply pause or stop your virtual machine then simply copy the .img, .raw or .qcow2 as the backup.

But i have suggestion for you: you can use easily  get a snapshot.

get snapshot with qemu-img:

> qemu-img snapshot -c backup /vms/vm10001.qcow2

or virsh command:

> virsh snapshot-create vm10001

Comment: Thank you for the information.